# Swift add ATTrackingManager - cannot find key in info.plist

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add ATTrackingManager to IOS project, I'm not Swift developer so went step by step with some docs and theoretically I did everything correctly yet app still crash.

So basically I did something like this:

```
func handleTrackingAuth() {
     if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
                switch status {
                    case .notDetermined:
                        print("ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined", status)
                        break
                    case .restricted:
                        print("ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted", status)
                        break
                    case .denied:
                        print("ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied", status)
                        break
                    case .authorized:
                        print("ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized", status)
                        break
                    @unknown default:
                    print("ATTracking no data", status)
                        break
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

and added it into **applicationDidBecomeActive** part.

Then I updated my GoogleService-Info.plist with proper key:

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs permission to track you across apps and websites owned by 3rd parties.</string>
```

yet still app crashes with error

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
> data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
> an NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key with a string value explaining
> to the user how the app uses this data.

I thought that perhaps Xcode didn't refresh files so I cleaned build folder and restarted Xcode yet still get same error. Does anyone know why it doesn't detect that key is added?

[image]

Comment: write it in the app info.plist file instead GoogleService-Info.plist

Comment: hello @RajaKishan Info.plist seems to be updated automatically:
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
 <array>
  <string>The app gathers information on how you interact with videos and point system.</string>
  <string>This app needs permission to track you across apps and websites owned by 3rd parties. This identifier will be used to collect cookies about your internet activity.</string>
 </array>

Comment: "updated automatically: " I dont think.

Comment: I updated my question with pic from info.plist, seems like proper rules are there, or am I wrong?

Comment: the value should be in String for ```NSUserTrackingUsageDescription```

Comment: in the image, the type is showing an array. it should be a string.

Comment: oh it works! Sorry, I got project from someone, there was already array and thought that that's how it should be. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription`, the type should be `string`.

in the image, the type is showing an array. it should be a string.